# How to avoid magic number warning when initialize static field (for example BigDecimal)?

Tags: java, initialization, field, bigdecimal, checkstyle

I have static field

```
private static final BigDecimal MAX_AMOUNT = BigDecimal.valueOf(299_999L);
```

And I get warning from CheckStyle that `299_999L` is magic number. 
How can I avoid this - 299_999 is just long transform into specified `BigDecimal`.

I did not find in CheckStyle documentation any suitable solution.

**EDIT**:
It comes out when I type for example:

```
private static final BigDecimal MAX_AMOUNT = BigDecimal.valueOf(299_999L).setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF-EVEN)
```

Comment: Interesting! I can't reproduce this behavior. Which version of Checkstyle are you using? Can you share the `MagicNumber` config from your *checkstyle.xml*? According to the [docs](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#MagicNumber), you should not get this warning.

Comment: Auch my bad. It comes out when I type BigDecimal.valueOf(299_999L).setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF-EVEN);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your clarifying comment, I can say that the reason for the warning is in the way the *MagicNumber* check works. *If* the potential magic number is in a field definition, and that field is `final`, then it is *not* flagged as long as all parent tokens in the AST up to the node representing the field definition are in a certain list.

This is quite confusing, and I think that to a normal user, it seems arbitrary. But static code analysis is often about heuristics.

The good thing is you can influence this behavior. Configure the check like this:

```xml
<module name="MagicNumber">
    <property name="constantWaiverParentToken"
        value="TYPECAST, METHOD_CALL, EXPR, ARRAY_INIT, UNARY_MINUS, UNARY_PLUS, ELIST, STAR, ASSIGN, PLUS, MINUS, DIV, LITERAL_NEW, DOT"/>
</module>
```

The value of `constantWaiverParentToken` is the default *plus* `DOT` added to the end. This allows for more complex expressions. You need at least Checkstyle 6.11 for this to work.

Comment: It should be noted that `constantWaiverParentToken` doesn't take into account the method being called, so it will hide violations where the method is changing the constant's value or if there are multiple constants in the method call.

Answer (score 2):

It is interesting that you are getting this error while declaring a static field. But any how you can add suppresswarning annotation,

```
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:magicnumber")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a constant to describe a little more of what that value means:

```
private static final Long MAX_AMOUNT_INITIALIZER = 299_000L;
private static final BigDecimal MAX_AMOUNT = BigDecimal.valueOf(MAX_AMOUNT_INITIALIZER);
```

It sounds redundant but remember that a magic number is any number used along the code that does not have any explanation of its meaning. Even though you have a `BigDecimal` constant, your `Long` value is not interpreted as a "meaningful value" for the context.